# String Detecting in R

Tags: r, regex, string, detect, stringr

I have the following strings.

```
x <- c("A1A1A1", "A3V???", "B4F3**")
```

I want to flag only the strings in which the last 3 characters do not follow the patter `[[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][[:digit]]`

Thus, I would want to flag the 2nd and 3rd string above.  Any suggestions?

Comment: `!grepl(".*([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][[:digit:]])$", x)` to flag them and will give `TRUE` values for the 2nd and 3rd string

Comment: and `grep(".*([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]][[:digit:]])$", x, value = TRUE)` to return just the one that meets the condition: `A1A1A1`

Comment: Try `(?:[^\d]..|.[^a-zA-Z].|..[^\d])$` because, no matter how you write it, the engine has to take these steps, so why not just write it like this.

Answer (score 0):

`grepl` is suitable here

```
> !grepl("\\d\\w\\d$", x)
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

If you want to get the position:

```
> grep("\\d\\w\\d$", x, invert = TRUE)
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, are you trying to remove those strings that do not follow that pattern? The way i can think of doing this is `clnstrings <- str_remove_all(vectornameofstrings, "symbols or patterns that you would want removed")`
There are probably more efficient ways to do this, but from my knowledge (which is limited, as I am still learning) this could be a way to do it. If anyone else has any input on this answer please don't hesitate to comment!